# How to continue dialog from call back in Microsoft Bot Framework NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, botframework

I am making a function call in one step of a dialog, and the response of the function will be retrieved in a callback function, based on response received in callback i need to continue or repeat the step, how do i do that, as once it gets into call back, context will be as undefined.

```
  async mySecondStep(step) {

    await client.createProfileAsync(
        sdk.VoiceProfileType.TextIndependentIdentification,
        locale,
        async (result) => {
            var profile = result;
            if (profile) {
                //continue dialog
            }
            else {
                //repeat dialog
            }

        }
   
   }
```

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes Resolved, did a workaround by holding request until i get callback response